Unknown Type Name 'uint32_t' after setting up Vulkan 1.3 on Mac M2 with XCode 16.2
Environment: Macbook Air M2 Sequoia, Xcode 16.2, VulkanSDK 1.3, glfw 3.4, glm 1.0.1
Error Description: Build failure due to header reference error. The main.cpp includes a header glfw.h which includes another header vulkan.h which includes another header vulkan_core.h, which uses uint32_t to typedef an alias. And uint32_t cannot be recoginzed, even though stdint.h already included in glfw.h. This happens when running the test code from vulkan-tutorials after setting up Xcode.
Error: Unknown Type Name 'uint32_t'
Error Location: vulkan_core.h
Code:
main.cpp (copied from vulkan-tutorials#setting up Xcode)
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

GLFW/glfw3.h
#include <stdint.h>

#if defined(GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN)
  #include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#endif /* Vulkan header */

vulkan/vulkan.h
#include "vulkan_core.h"

vulkan_core.h
...
typedef uint32_t VkBool32;
typedef uint64_t VkDeviceAddress;
typedef uint64_t VkDeviceSize;
typedef uint32_t VkFlags;
typedef uint32_t VkSampleMask;
...

I have followed the instructions on vulkan-tutorial#setting-up-Xcode. The only difference is I have used /opt/homebrew/Cellar instead of /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib to set up the header/lib search paths in search path tab of building settings, and I've set the link as recursive. Both of glfw and glm are installed under /opt/homebrew/Cellar.
I have checked the stdint.h. It is correctly installed to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h and I've make sure it works well in other projects.
I’ve also tried adding the header <stdint.h> directly to the main.cpp file, but that didn’t correct the error.
I am new to Xcode so there might be some thing I don't know about.
Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Do not put the answer in the question. There is a question field and an answer field. The question field is for the question. If you have an answer to your own question, put it in the answer field. Or just delete the question if you feel it isn't useful to others.

Solution: Change the header search paths from /opt/homebrew/Cellar to the specific path of glfw/include and glm/include. /opt/homebrew/Cellar contains too much lib and installation which might cofuse Xcode when searching the header recursively.
The proper header search paths should look like this:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glfw/3.4/include
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glm/1.0.1/include
vulkansdk/macOS/include
# vulkansdk is the specific path to VulkanSDK.

Set the search method from non-recursive to recursive and then the build should succeed.
